# Getting next matching string value from a SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

My SQL table have a column name AddressName . I am storing customer address name in that column. And I want to store them in the following format, suppose when I inserted first time a value in that column it stored 'Utpal' in that field next time before inserting any value I want to fetch the next string value to be inserted as 'Utpal2' and will insert that value in the table.Similarly in the next insertion the value should be 'Utpal3'.How to do this task using SQL query please help.

Thanks and Regards

Utpal Maity

Comment: Have you tried anything by yourself yet?

Comment: Is there a column to store entered `AddressName` and new created `AddressName`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this would help you. Just an example:

TABLE SCHEMA:

```
create table person
(
  id int identity(1,1),
  address varchar(50)
)
GO
```

SCRIPT: (partial)

```
--insert second record
insert into person
select top 1 left(address, case patindex('%[0-9]%', address) when 0 then len(address) else patindex('%[0-9]%', address) - 1 end) + 
       convert(varchar(10),convert(numeric(10,0),Coalesce(NULLIF(right(address, case patindex('%[0-9]%', address) 
                                                                                when 0 then 0 
                                                                                else len(address) - patindex('%[0-9]%', address) + 1
                                                                                end
                                                                      )
                                                               ,'')
                                                        ,0)
                                 ) + 1
              )from person
order by id desc
GO
```

Check out [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b3664/68):

Comment: Hi NeverHopeless,                                                                        Your query will work all the address name will store using this value'utpal' if the table store values in below format then this will not give the desire result 
Address   CustomerId  

Utpal      001
Utpal1     001
Maity      001
Utpal2     0001

Now I want to insert Utpal3 what are the way?

Thanks
Utpal

Comment: @user2342089, please check my updates. It may not a simple one but will do the job